# No response from nodejs api

Tags: node.js, api, express

This is my code i tried to send a request through http://localhost:3000/api/post/article using postman but i received cannot get as error. 
It's working without using router.get but instead using app.get, so i think the problem is with the router.

This is the server.js file

```
 const http = require("http");
 const app = require("./app");
 app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);
 const server = http.createServer(app);
 server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

this is the app file

```
const express = require("express");
const postRoutes = require("./routes/post");
const app = express();  
app.use("api/post", postRoutes);
module.exports = app;
```

This is the router file

```
 const express = require("express");
 const router = express.Router();
 const postCtrl = require("../controllers/post");
 router.get("/article", postCtrl.specArticle);
 module.exports = router;
```

This is the controller file

```
 module.exports.specArticle = (req, res) => {

res.status(200).json({ message: "working currently" });
};
```

Comment: For starters, this `app.use("api/post", postRoutes);` should be this `app.use("/api/post", postRoutes);`.  Not sure if that fixes your issue, but it's definitely should be fixed.

Comment: FYI, `.status(200)` is not needed.  `200` is the default status already.

Comment: Doesn't a "cannot get" error typically mean that postman can't contact the http server?  I"d say you should add a 404 handler to your server so you would get a 404 error if the request is getting to your server, but it isn't matching a route.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
app.use("api/post", postRoutes);
```

to this:

```
app.use("/api/post", postRoutes);
```

As best I know, all paths in your route handlers should start with `/` (at least I have no idea why you would ever not start them with a `/`).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a misconfigured rollbar line:

```
require('./server/rollbar')(app);
```